# Send JSON stringify to PHP how to read it

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

In javascript i am using JSON.stringify it generate the below string

```
{"grid":[{"section":[{"id":"wid-id-1-1"},{"id":"wid-id-1-4"}]},{"section":[{"id":"wid-id-1-5"}]},{"section":[{"id":"wid-id-1-2"},{"id":"wid-id-1-3"}]}]}
```

i am calling php using ajax, i can get the string in PHP as it is, but after that how i should process it.

Below is my full code

```
 var mainArr = [];
        $('.sortable-grid')
                .each(function() {
                    var subArr = [];
                    $(this)
                            .children('.mygrid')
                            .each(function() {
                                var subObj = {};
                                subObj['id'] = $(this)
                                        .attr('id');
                                subArr.push(subObj);
                            });
                    var out = {
                        'section': subArr
                    };
                    mainArr.push(out);
                });

        var storePositionObj = JSON.stringify({
            'grid': mainArr
        });

$.ajax({
            url: __BASEURL + "php/update-details.php",
            data: {position: storePositionObj},
```

I recently started learning PHP, and don't know how to process this above string.

could any one please help.

thank you

regards,
Mona

Comment: When using jQuery there's no need to stringify the object, and in PHP there's no need to decode it, you're overthinking it.

Comment: can i pass direct object?

Comment: Yes you can, and jQuery will convert it to form/urlencoded so you don't have decode it in PHP, just pass the object directly and access the keys with the PHP superglobals (POST, GET, REQUEST etc).

Comment: thanks adeneo you are right i can directly pass object.. but now i have other problem...
[0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["section"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(10) "wid-id-1-1"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(10) "wid-id-1-4"
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["section"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(10) "wid-id-1-5"
      }
    }
  }
How i can read this in loop/or access it

Comment: It's just an array, you can access it with `$_REQUEST['grid'][0]['section']` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json = json_decode($_POST['position']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

sample code below:

```
<?PHP
    $position = $_REQUEST['position'];
    print_r(json_decode($position));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use json_decode() method and then you  can use it like an array.

You can use it like

```
$data = json_decode($your_stringify_json);
var_dump($data['grid']);
```

Comment: to use the array, need to add 2nd parameter: $data = json_decode($strJson, true);